# angularJS factory testing using a stand-alone jasmine server only

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angularjs-factory

I am learning how to write AngularJS tests using a stand-alone jasmine server only.
I was successfully able to test a controller however, I'm having trouble testing a factory that I wrote. I get an error like,

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

(Factory code) myservice.js:

```
mod.factory('WeatherService', function ($http) {
    return {
        testingdata: function () {
            return {name: "test", class: "ix"};
        }
};});
```

app.js

```
var mod = angular.module("myapp", []);
```

my test:

```
describe("ws", function () {
    describe('when I call WeatherService', function () {
        it('returns 1', function () {
            var t = {name: "test", class: "ix"};
            var $injector = angular.injector(['myapp']);
            var WeatherService= $injector.get('WeatherService');
            expect(WeatherService.testingdata).toEqual(t);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing#jasmine) for correct injection of modules and providers in Jasmine. There's a system function `inject()` that does the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is unnecessarily complicated.

You do not use angular.injector in test - you can use module function from ngMock

Similarly instead of $injector.get you can use function inject from ngMock module.

```
describe("ws", function() {

  beforeEach(module('myapp'));

  describe('when I call WeatherService', function() {
    it('returns 1', inject(function(WeatherService) {
      var t = {
        name: "test",
        class: "ix"
      };

      expect(WeatherService.testingdata()).toEqual(t);
    }));
  });
});
```

here is working example http://plnkr.co/edit/doBJeWRyVyD75LfRP4G4?p=preview